# Mail merge with looping/grouping

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word, mailmerge

I have an Excel table, which I use to do a mail merge into word.

[image: Excel Table]

The mail merge is done through this code

```
'starting the mail merge for the main body of the report
Set wdDoc = wdApp.Documents.Open(fNameW)
wdDoc.Activate
wdDoc.MailMerge.OpenDataSource Name:=(fNameE), Revert:=False, Connection:="Entire Spreadsheet", SQLStatement:="SELECT * FROM `'Table of Recommendations$'`", SQLStatement1:=""
With wdDoc.MailMerge
    .MainDocumentType = wdFormLetters
    .Destination = wdSendToNewDocument
    .SuppressBlankLines = True
    With .DataSource
        .FirstRecord = wdDefaultFirstRecord
        .LastRecord = wdDefaultLastRecord
    End With
    .Execute
    
    For Each wd In ActiveDocument.StoryRanges
    With wd.Find
        .Text = "(blank)"
        .Replacement.Text = ""
        .Forward = True
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
        .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    End With
    
    With wd.Find
        .Text = "^b"
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        While .Execute
            wd.Delete
            wd.InsertParagraph
        Wend
    End With
    Next wd
```

And this is the output I get:

[image]

Now, my question. What I would like to achieve is that recommendation number (b) gets inserted in the first table, just under recommendation number (a), based on the fact that the two recommendations arise from the same issue *Country Cooperation*. In other words, the merge process should loop through the Excel table and if the issue is the same, it should group the recommendations together, omit the blank cells, and not generate the second table. Do you think this is possible? If yes, can you point me in the right direction? I have searched allover the internet but have not been able to find any solution. Thank you.

Comment: From what I can tell from the image you posted, there is no second table - only a single 'Strategy' table. For what you want, check out the *Calculating Group and Sub-Group Totals* topic my **Microsoft Word Catalogue/Directory Mailmerge Tutorial**, available at: https://www.msofficeforums.com/mail-merge/38721-microsoft-word-catalogue-directory-mailmerge-tutorial.html. The approach there could readily be adapted to your needs. Your workbook would, of course, need to have the same 'Issue Title' for all rows that are to be grouped together.

Comment: Thank you @macropod. I had already found your guidelines (which are very well done) on the internet, and I had already tried that way. The problem I have is that the table breaks and drops one enter key after each one of the lines that gets repeated. In other words, if there is an issue with two recommendations, the table will break before the first recommendation (and an enter line will be inserted), and then it will break again before the second recommendation (with another enter line being inserted). I have spent considerable time to try and keep the table together, but no success.

Comment: As discussed (and supplied) in the tutorial, there is a TableJoiner macro to handle that...

Comment: Thank you. This looks very promising. I will try it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved my problem following the suggestions given by @macropod. Using the guideline available at https://www.msofficeforums.com/mail-merge/38721-microsoft-word-catalogue-directory-mailmerge-tutorial.html, I was able to sort the issue out. I set-up the mail merge template as described in page 4 of the afire guideline, added the table joiner macro described in pages 20/21 of the afore guidelines and solved my issue. Below a sample of the code I wrote:

```
'starting the mail merge for the main body of the report
With wdApp 'launching Ms Word
fNameW = "C:\Users\" & uName & "\OneDrive...\Main Body.dotx"
.Visible = True
.Documents.Open fNameW, , ReadOnly

Set wdDoc = wdApp.Documents.Open(fNameW)
wdDoc.Activate
wdDoc.MailMerge.OpenDataSource Name:=(fNameE), Revert:=False, Connection:="Entire Spreadsheet", SQLStatement:="SELECT * FROM `'Table of Recommendations$'`", SQLStatement1:=""
With wdDoc.MailMerge
    .MainDocumentType = wdCatalog
    .Destination = wdSendToNewDocument
    .SuppressBlankLines = True
    With .DataSource
        .FirstRecord = wdDefaultFirstRecord
        .LastRecord = wdDefaultLastRecord
    End With
    .Execute
    
    For Each wd In ActiveDocument.StoryRanges
    With wd.Find
        .Text = "(blank)"
        .Replacement.Text = ""
        .Forward = True
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
        .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    End With
    Next wd
    
    For Each oPara In ActiveDocument.Paragraphs
        With oPara.Range
            If .Information(wdWithInTable) = True Then
                 With .Next
                    If .Information(wdWithInTable) = False Then
                        If .Text = vbCr Then .Delete
                    End If
                End With
            End If
        End With
    Next
    
    ChangeFileOpenDirectory fod
    ActiveDocument.SaveAs2 Filename:=fnameMB, FileFormat:=wdFormatXMLDocument, LockComments:=False, Password:="", AddToRecentFiles:=True, WritePassword:="", ReadOnlyRecommended:=False, EmbedTrueTypeFonts:=False, SaveNativePictureFormat:=False, SaveFormsData:=False, SaveAsAOCELetter:=False, CompatibilityMode:=15
    ActiveDocument.Close

End With

Sheets("Table of Recommendations").Select
Range(rangeTC).Select
Selection.Clear

wdDoc.Close savechanges:=wdDoNotSaveChanges
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Done, I hope it is fine now.

Answer (score 1):

I do propose that you change your data! Include e.g. "RecommendationText" values which you have in two cells now into one multiline cell:

```
(a) Expedite an evaluation ... [AltGr][Enter]
(b) Develop, publish and disseminate
```

Comment: Thank you, but that is not possible. The Excel table comes from a database via a power query and it comes in this format.

Answer (score 1):

1. add a concatenating column to a copy of your database data
   =IF($C13="",E12&CHAR(10)&D13,E12)  ... for the row 12 in the example below
2. filter your data for non empty lines (e.g. col "Background")

.
.
**Screenshot with "concatenating column"**
[image]

.
.
**Screenshot filtered data**
[image]